# connect to mysql database which is in ubuntu server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, azure, virtual-machine

I am using below code to connect `MySQL` database in `PHP`.

```
try {
    shell_exec("ssh -f -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 ronak@server_ip sleep 60 >> logfile");
    $this->_conn = $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_db', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Couldn't connect to database. Please try again!");
}
```

I want to direct connect with remote MySQL host. Server is on azure virtual machine. How can I do such a configurations?

I already opened `3306` port in azure portal for MySQL. I don't know how to use it in here without ssh tunnel.

Thanks.

Comment: Can u connect to azure:3306 thru the likes of SQL Workbench?

Comment: No. in workbench also I need to connect it with SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) change my.conf (whatever your mysql conf file is called). And set bind-address to 0.0.0.0 as it is prob 127.0.0.1

2) stop/restart mysql daemon

`Connections now are not limited to those from localhost (what you are when you ssh). The default is localhost for obvious security reason until dev guy tweaks it`

3) add database user perhaps coming in from diff ip addr

```
CREATE USER 'fred7'@'192.168.2.7' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
```

4) grants

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test7db.* TO 'fred7'@'192.168.2.7';
```

5) firewall

For 3 and 4, let's say the mysql server is on aws ec2 and i am sitting at a public library using sqlyog or workbench. That prog will alert me if connect failure stating something like `connection failed for user 'fred7'@'gfs6.nyc.comcastbusiness.net'`. So it is pretty obvious how to do 3 and 4 then.

Good luck!

Comment: Once one can connect remotely with the likes of SQL Workbench, I would bet Sir Patel will not be resorting to SSH at all